# Is there an alternative replacement motor piece for 4.5 V Trains?

Tags: motor, trains

Is it possible to find on a market a simple 4.5V electric motor, that can be installed into [LEGO Part 564c01](http://rebrickable.com/parts/564c01)?

[The service pack No. 5000](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/5000_Replacement_4.5_V_Motor) is more and more difficult to find.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the assembly is correctly greased - they can throw a lot of sqeak out if they are needing a little grease even if the motor is fine!

I have looked in to this myself, but the cost and trouble just isn't worth it - you can buy a used working unit for around £8 to £12 from a used / vintage Lego parts site.

These motors are really good quality and almost last forever if looked after, so chances are you will get your £8 - £12 worth from a quality used one - regular off-the-shelf motors cost anywhere from £4 - £8 and that's if you can get a perfect size and voltage match not to mention getting the drive gear to fit it etc. Stick with buying a using original motor/full assembly and check it is suitably greased and looked after it

I have lots of Lego train sets and that was my answer to non-working motors. I look after them well, and they just keep going!